# How to capture screen at boot phase (when Autochk is running)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, boot

I would like to write a code which is able to capture the screen at boot phase (when Autochk is running) and write to file. What is the best approach?

From what I know at this phase only ntdll.dll is available...so we can use this native API to open the Mirror Driver to get the screen data. However in order to  get data from mirror driver we will need the GDI library which is not available yet. What should I do?

Comment: Isn't the screen in text mode at that point?

Comment: I think it is already switch to graphics mode, but the printing content is just text

Comment: This is not a C or C++ related issue.  Don't tag them as such, please.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that Windows is running Windows code at that time, not yours. There's possibly an exception for (disk) drivers, but since you're talking about calling Win32 DLL's that doesn't matter. You can't call GDI from a driver. Besides, why would your driver be called in the first place? Drivers react to OS requests to handle specific events.

Comment: we can register an app run at boot before Autochk, this app will fork another process and exit the current. So Autochk and other app can run. Another process will periodically call the driver to get the screen data and save to disk.